# Checking if there is at least 3 equal elements in an array

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a code that determines if there is at least 3 equal elements in an array of numbers.

For example, if i have the array:

```
[1,5,5,5]
```

Then output:

```
True
```

Example 2:

```
[5,5,5,5]
```

Outputs:

```
True
```

Example 3:

```
[1,1,5,5]
```

Output:

```
False
```

I've tried:

```
arr = [1,5,5,5]
count = 0
for i in range(len(arr)-1):
    if arr[i] == arr[i+1]:
        count +=1;

if count >=3:
   print("True")
else:
   print("False")
```

But I'm getting the output:

```
False
```

which should be true in this case since there are indeed at least 3 equal elements in the array.

Comment: Use `counter` and check for frequency > 3

Comment: Are the elements sorted? If yes then use `itertools.groupby`: `any(len(list(group)) for _, group in groupby(arr))`

Comment: `False` is the correct output.  Your count never reaches 3 since it never compares '5' to '5' 3 times.  1 != 5, and the 3rd '5' is not only the last element in the list, but also the last '5' so it is never compared against anything.  You would need 4 '5's (in a row) to reach a count of 3.

Also, your code only works if the 3 numbers are consecutive.

Comment: do they need to be consecutive ? ie for list `[5 ,1, 5, 2, 5]`  should it print `True` ?

Comment: I am asking you this because the way you are trying to solve this problem is like you are trying to determine if there are at least three same consecutive elements but from your question one can interpret that they can be anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

There is a typo in your example use `count>=2`:

```
if count >=2:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

Remember you increase +1 if you find the second '5' and another increment is done when you find the third '5'.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Counter`

```
def check(my_list):
    from collections import Counter
    counter = Counter(my_list)
    return max(counter.values()) > = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a Counter:

```
from collections import Counter

def has_3_repeats(arr):
    counter = Counter(arr)
    return any(val >= 3 for val in counter.values())
```

If you have an enormous array, you can do this lazily, stopping as soon as you need to:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def has_3_repeats_lazy(arr):
    counter = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    for x in arr:
        counter[x] += 1
        if counter[x] >= 3:
            return True

    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
from collections import defaultdict

arr = [1,5,5,5] # True if arr = [1,5,5,7,5] then also it should print True

num_count_dict = defaultdict(int)

for num in arr:
    num_count_dict[num]+= 1
    if num_count_dict[num] == 3:
        print("True")
        break
else:
   print("False")
```

2)

```
# They need to be consecutive
arr2 = [1,5,5,5] # True but if arr2 = [1,5,5,7,5] it should print False


count =0
for i in range(len(arr2)-1):
    if arr2[i] == arr2[i+1]:
        count += 1
    else:
        count = 1 # count of new number

    if count == 3:
        print("True")
        break
else:
   print("False")
```